# How to add a Picasso image to the ArrayList using firebase

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I want to list.add images stored in my Firebase using listArray> list;.

Please let me know if there is a way to get the image itself, not the address stored in the firebase in the listArray, without having to attach it through Picasso.

We would also like to invite you to format this data to the next activity in Intent.putExtra().

```
public class Menu2_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ImageView image;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Jellyfish jellyfish;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu2_1);

        jellyfish = new Jellyfish();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref = database.getReference("Jellyfish");
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Jellyfish>(this, R.layout.jellyfish_info, R.id.jellyfishinfo, list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.jellyfish_info, R.id.jellyfishinfo, list);
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    jellyfish = ds.getValue(Jellyfish.class);
                    list.add(jellyfish.getName() + "\n" + jellyfish.getSpot() + "\n" + jellyfish.getToxic()
                    + jellyfish.getImage());

                    Picasso.with(Menu2_1.this).load(jellyfish.getImage()).into(image);
                }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Jellyfish_Page.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", list.get(position));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You want to pass the image url to next activity ?

Comment: If you need image itself then you have to download image using image address.

Comment: No, I only want to send images I use firebase And 
intent.putExtra ("name", list.get (position)) of source code attached to attach image to arraylist; I want to send like